Dataflow Job Running Successfully, but No DAG is Created in Cloud Dataflow Console
I’m currently working with Apache Beam and Google Cloud Dataflow, and I’ve encountered an issue where my Dataflow job is executing successfully, but no Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) is visible in the Cloud Dataflow Console.
Problem:
The Dataflow job runs successfully, but no DAG is visible in the Cloud Dataflow Console.
The job status is Running or Succeeded, but the visualization for the DAG is missing.
Code
import json
import datetime
import argparse
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions, StandardOptions
from apache_beam.transforms.window import FixedWindows

class ParsePubSubMessage(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        try:
            element = json.loads(element.decode('utf-8'))
            yield element['customer_id'], element['purchase_amount'], element['time_stamp']
        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            print(f"Failed to decode message: {e}")

class CustomTimeStamp(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, elements):
        if len(elements) > 2:
            try:
                unix_timestamp = float(elements[2])
                
                if unix_timestamp < 0 or unix_timestamp > 2**31:
                    raise ValueError("Timestamp out of range")

                yield beam.window.TimestampedValue(elements, unix_timestamp)
            except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
                print(f"Invalid timestamp {elements[2]}: {e}")
                default_timestamp = float(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())
                yield beam.window.TimestampedValue(elements, default_timestamp)
        else:
            print(f"Element does not have enough items: {elements}")
            yield None

class ParseFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        yield (element[0], float(element[1]))

class FormatOutputFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
        customer_id, total_purchase = element
        try:
            start = window.start.to_utc_datetime()
            end = window.end.to_utc_datetime()
            output_str = f"{customer_id}: ${total_purchase}, Window: {start} - {end}"
            print(output_str)
            yield output_str.encode('utf-8')
        except OverflowError:
            yield f"{customer_id}: ${total_purchase}, Invalid timestamp".encode('utf-8')

def customer_data_aggregation(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('--input_subscription', dest='input_subscription', required=True, help='Pub/Sub subscription to read from')
    parser.add_argument('--output_topic', dest='output_topic', required=True, help='Pub/Sub topic to write to')
    parser.add_argument('--runner', dest='runner', default='DirectRunner', help='Runner type (DirectRunner or DataflowRunner)')
    parser.add_argument('--project', dest='project', required=False, help='Google Cloud Project ID')
    parser.add_argument('--temp_location', dest='temp_location', required=False, help='Temporary storage location for Dataflow (e.g., gs://bucket/temp)')
    parser.add_argument('--region', dest='region', required=False, help='Google Cloud region (e.g., us-central1)')
    parser.add_argument('--job_name', dest='job_name', required=False, help='Dataflow job name')
    parser.add_argument('--streaming', dest='streaming', action='store_true', help='Specify this flag to run the pipeline in streaming mode')

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

    if known_args.runner == 'DataflowRunner':
        google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
        google_cloud_options.project = known_args.project
        google_cloud_options.temp_location = known_args.temp_location
        google_cloud_options.region = known_args.region
        google_cloud_options.job_name = known_args.job_name

    if known_args.streaming:
        options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True

    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        purchases = (
            p
            | 'Read from PubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.input_subscription)
            | "Parse Pubsub Data" >> beam.ParDo(ParsePubSubMessage())
            | 'Custom Timestamp' >> beam.ParDo(CustomTimeStamp())
            | 'Filter None' >> beam.Filter(lambda x: x is not None)
        )

        windowed_purchases = (
            purchases
            | 'Apply Fixed Window' >> beam.WindowInto(FixedWindows(30))
            | 'Parse CSV' >> beam.ParDo(ParseFn())
            | 'Sum Purchases' >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum)
        )

        formatted_output = (
            windowed_purchases
            | 'Format Output' >> beam.ParDo(FormatOutputFn())
            | "Write To PubSub" >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=known_args.output_topic)
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    customer_data_aggregation()

Command to Run the Pipeline:
python fixed_window.py \
    --input_subscription=projects/project-id/subscriptions/customer-topic-2-sub \
    --output_topic=projects/project-id/topics/topic-12 \
    --runner=DataflowRunner \
    --project=project-id \
    --temp_location=gs://customer_data_analysis/temp/ \
    --region=us-central1 \
    --streaming \
    --job_name=my-dataflow-job

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified that the Dataflow job is executing and logging.
Checked pipeline options and arguments.
Ensured that the job name is valid and unique.
Attempted to refresh the Dataflow Console page.
Simplified the pipeline to test DAG creation.

Questions:

Are there any specific issues that could prevent the DAG from being created or displayed?
How can I further diagnose why the DAG visualization is missing?
Are there any additional steps I can take to ensure that the DAG is created and visible?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Hi @Lokesh K V, Could you confirm if you are using the latest version of the Apache Beam SDK which is compatible with cloud DataFlow ? Also Did you try Re-Run the job or pipeline ? Sometimes re-running the job might resolve the transient issue. Let me know if this helped you or not.

Hi @Dhiraj Singh, Thank you for your suggestion. I'm using Apache Beam SDK version 2.59 which is the latest and should be compatible with Google Cloud Dataflow. I’ve re-run the job, but the DAG still does not appear in the Dataflow Console. Do you have any further recommendations for troubleshooting the DAG to appear in the Dataflow Console manually? Additional insights would be greatly appreciated. You can review my code and set it up in my GitHub repository: Repo

Do you have all the required permission for the GCP like `dataflow.developer`, `dataflow.viewer` ?

Yes, I did set up the service account with the mentioned above permission and completed a Demo Dataflow Job.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#permissions better check this. Going through this simple guide https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/create-pipeline-python could help setup all the permissons.

Hi @Lokesh K V, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
